# Accessing Values in Lists from a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a clean data frame which is just a list of addresses. Next used python library called [usaddress](https://github.com/datamade/usaddress) which returns a list of tuples when I applied them to my pandas column.
It returns

```
[('1234', 'AddressNumber'), ('S', 'StreetNamePreDirectional'), ('Bervely', 
'StreetName'), ('RD', 'StreetNamePostType'),...]
```

I want to have each left value of each have its own column. I've tried writing a function to get the values of the tuples but I keep getting  a list error.

When I write

```
def addressDirection(df):
    return df[0:2][1:2][0]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

I can only get the tuples into their own columns and not their values. Here is my code.

```
def addressDirection(df):
    return df[0:2][1:2]
```

It returns

```
[(E, StreetNamePreDirectional)]
```

**Original data**

```
string_addr
1234 S Berverly BLVD KANSAS TX 1235
1234 S Berverly BLVD KANSAS TX 1235
1234 S Berverly BLVD KANSAS TX 1235
```

After I apply the usaaddress python library. The entire column looks like

```
   addr_breakdown

[('1234', 'AddressNumber'), ('S', 'StreetNamePreDirectional'), ('Berverly', 'StreetName'), ('BLVD', 'StreetNamePostType'), ('KANSAS', 'PlaceName'), ('MO', 'StateName'), ('1235', 'ZipCode')]
```

But I just want E.
 **Expected Result:**

```
 Number Direction   Street  PostType    City    State   ZipCode
 1234     S          Berverly BLVD      O-Town   xy       1234
```

**What I have now**

```
 Number Direction   Street  PostType                  City  
  1234         [('S', 'StreetNamePreDirectional') [('Berverly  ','StreetName')]  ....
```

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data, orient='columns') ?

Comment: Use `df  = pd.DataFrame(L)`

Comment: what is expected result

Comment: I updated my comment. Maybe I should just do regex